# PHP never testing true for file_exists while evaluating array value

Tags: php

My problem is I set an array value to the name of a server as follow:

```
$appserver[$i]=`grep $ip[2] /etc/hosts |awk '{print $2}'`;
```

Later I do a test to see if the server is up or not (using a wget).
If the test fails I keep track of that server being down by creating a file with that
name using touch:

```
$touch=`touch /home/steve/data/$appserver[$i];
```

The file gets created successfully.
Later when I go to test whether or not the file exists it never evaluates to true.

```
if(file_exists('/home/steve/data/$appserver[$i])) {
```

I have tried several different things including creating a new variable for 
$appserver[$i] and testing against it, which also does not work:

I am running php 5.1.6 on RHEL 5.

Here is the full code:

```
  $appserver[$i]=`grep $ip[2] /etc/hosts |awk '{print $2}'`;
  echo "appserver[i] = $appserver[$i]\n";
   $get=`wget $key->url 2> /dev/null`;
   if(file_exists('/home/user/Start')) {
            $color[$i]="green";
            $rm=`rm -rf /home/user/Start`;
    }
    else {
            $color[$i]="red";
            if($hostname=="xxxxx" ) {
                    **if(file_exists('/home/user/data/$appserver[$i]))**  {**
                        echo "do nothing appserver file exists\n";
                        $touch=`touch /home/steve/data/notmailed`;
                        }
                    else {
                    echo "No app file mailed alert\n";
                    $touch=`touch /home/user/data/$appserver[$i]`;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: `'$appserver[$i]' != "$appserver[$i]"`

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/$appserver[$i]")) {
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have tried a very small program that shows how this is still failing. [root@dsmpp1 steve]# ls -l data
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 11:41 test_file
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# cat test_file.php
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
$i=1;
$testarray=array();
$testarray[$i]="test_file";
echo "testarray  $testarray[$i]\n";
if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/testarray[$i]")) {
        echo "file exists\n";
}
        else {
                echo "file does not exist\n";
        }
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# php -q test_file.php 
testarray  test_file
file does not exist
[root@dsmpp1 steve]#

Comment: You have an error in the code you pasted above, you have if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/testarray[$i]"))  and the correct is  if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/$testarray[$i]"))

Answer (score 1):

```
if(file_exists('/home/steve/data/$appserver[$i]')) {
```

`'` quoted strings do not interpolate variable values, so you're looking for a file whose literal name is `$appserver[$i]`. Use `"` quotes instead:

```
if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/$appserver[$i]")) {
```

Comment: Thank you however someone suggested that before and it still does not work.

Comment: Thank you Marc. I have tried using the double quotes and it still oes not pass.  I have hard coded the name of the server in place of $appserver[$i] just to make sure and it does pass when hard coded in.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried a very small program that shows how this is still failing. 
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# ls -l data
 total 4 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Sep 19 11:41 test_file 
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# cat test_file.php
 #!/usr/bin/php -q 
<?php 
$i=1; 
$testarray=array(); 
$testarray[$i]="test_file"; 
echo "testarray $testarray[$i]\n";
 if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/testarray[$i]")) {
 echo "file exists\n"; } 
else { echo "file does not exist\n"; } 
[root@dsmpp1 steve]# php -q test_file.php 
testarray test_file 
file does not exist 
[root@dsmpp1 steve]#

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$appserver[$i] = "grep $ip[2] /etc/hosts |awk '{print $2}'";

//...

if(file_exists("/home/steve/data/$appserver[$i]"))
{
    //...
}
```

Ensure that you use double-qoutes (`"`) whereever you want the content of variables parsed into the declared string!

Comment: Thank you but someone else also suggested that and it still does not work.  I also tried it with the '/home/steve/data'.$appserver[$i]   with single quotes and does not work.